# Make the called url deal with client cookie not caller cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl, session-cookies

I'm making an app that deal with an `API`

So i'm trying to call the `API` using `cURL` and the issue is that the api will deal with the server cookie which do this curl call not the client cookie who use the app...

For Example : the client is already logged in to the api ,
but when i check if the client logged in by curl call , the api response that you are not authorithed

So how can i make the `API` deal with the client cookies or pass the cookie of client to the `API` ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a cookiefile, like so:

```
        # Set the cookiefile name, which will allow us to store the cookie and present it later for all requests that require it...
        $cookiefile = tempnam("/tmp", "cookies");
        $agent     = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";

        # Set the user name and password values
        $user      = $argv[1];
        $password      = $argv[2];

        # The API url, to do the login
        $url = "https://some_site.com/login.php?WID=$user&PW=$password";

        # Initialise CURL
        $ch = curl_init();

        # Set all the various options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_userAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); // set POST method
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_userPWD, $user.":".$password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

        # Execute the first CURL request to perform the login...
        $results = curl_exec($ch);

        # Setup our next request...
        $job_id_number      = $argv[3];
        $url = "https://some_site.com/request.php?task=add&taskID=$job_id_number";

        # We do not have to initialise CURL again, however we do need to adjust our URL option for the second request...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        #Remember to use the same cookiefile as above  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

        # Execute the second CURL call  to perform the action (using the cookie we retrieved from earlier)
        $results = curl_exec($ch);

        echo "$results";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation of the API.
Maybe the documentation describes a way to authorize the client.

This way it won't work, because the cookies are set at clientside (in the browser) and not at your server. So when you make a cURl call, the cookie data isn't included in the request.
An API call via Javascript could work, because that is a request that the client sends (with the needed cookies)

Comment: I know that the javascript call worked but what i need it using PHP

Comment: Then you have to read out all the cookies and send them with your cURL request. This is only possible if the cookies are set from your domain.